# Sharepoint - How to copy text column in PersonColumn

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need help.
I have a Sharepoint list, I have to copy the text values in "Person (Text)" (this is a standard text column) into a new column: "Person (Person Or Group)" (this column isn't a text column,it is a particular column that Sharepoint provides me, that can recognize if a person is a part of my company and it gives me all the informations related to that person ex. Department, code ecc..)

I'm using  SharePoint in Microsoft 365 and I whist to get the text from one column and transform it into a Person Field

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZtIG.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you using SharePoint 2010? You wish to get the text from one column and transform it into a Person Field?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint in Microsoft 365 and I whish  get the text from one column and transform it into a Person Field

Comment: You could use a flow for that. Whenever a new item is created in the list you could use the value from the Person (text) column. Split that text on ;# and loop through the items with an apply to each. Within the loop use a Search for Users (v2) action and use the item(). If it has found a match update the item with that claim value of that user in the Person or Group field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set/update person or group column directly using text column. In SharePoint, person or group column is stored by using user ID (ID of user in hidden User Information List).

Try below workarounds:

1. If you have emails stored in text column: [Copy text column to a person column (in the same list)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/copy-text-column-to-a-person-column-in-the-same-list/m-p/2389184)
2. If you have names stored in text column: [Change column from single text to person or group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150926/change-column-from-single-text-to-person-or-group)